# Error when running JAR

Tags: java, executable-jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:15)
        at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I get this error which apparently has to do with my ImageIcon having an unknown source.  I think it has to do with the path given for the .png I used, but I don't know what to do about it.  Is there a special location where I need to place images for it to work as a JAR?

If it helps here's my code for the ImageIcon.

```
ImageIcon titleIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("mainBackground.png"));
```

Comment: at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source) just means it doesn't know what file:line it is. I think getResource is returning a null though, because it's happening in the ImageIcon constructor. I don't really know much about JARs and resources though so I can't really help there.

Comment: I'll try putting it outside the constructor and see what happens.

Comment: Try adding a `/` to the start of the path, ie `ImageIcon titleIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/mainBackground.png"))`, assuming that the image resource is stored in the root location of the Jar.  Also make sure that the resource is included in the Jar

Comment: @user1500190 better create a jar with resource directory which holds the all type files needed to the project ,and try to execute the jar so you could solve the problem of null pointer exception ,